# execute a command with each list from a text file

Tags: bash, loops, shell

I would like to execute a command with each list from a text file. I tried doing this code but it is not giving me any output. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
for i in $(cat list_of_text.txt)
do
    commandtool some_input_file $i> new_"$i".fa

    cat > final.list
    echo -e "new_"$i"\t+" >> final.list
done
```

list_of_text.txt looks like this

```
nameabc
namedef
nameghi
namejkl
```

while final.list looks like this

```
new_nameabc.fa  +
new_namedef.fa  +
new_nameghi.fa  +
new_namejkl.fa  +
```

In summary
the long version of the code is like this and I'm trying to make a shortcut:

```
commandtool some_input_file nameabc> new_nameabc.fa
commandtool some_input_file namedef> new_namedef.fa
commandtool some_input_file nameghi> new_nameghi.fa
commandtool some_input_file namejkl> new_namejkl.fa

echo -e "new_nameabc.fa\t+" > final.list
echo -e "new_namedef.fa\t+" >> final.list
echo -e "new_nameghi.fa\t+" >> final.list
echo -e "new_namejkl.fa\t+" >> final.list
```

Edit: It is working now. I just replaced `cat > final.list` to `echo > final.list` and moved it at the beginning as suggested in the answer.

Comment: An example of what `final.list` should look like when complete would be handy and what it looks like currently. As well as `list_of_text.txt`.
But in your loop, you are truncating `final.list` each time the loop is executed. Is that what is "not working"?

Comment: Also, `cat` will be waiting for input. I suspect you may want `echo` and have the initial `echo > final.list` before the loop code, not for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my post and added what those file would look like. I just wanted to make a shortcut of the long code I have at the end of my post.

Comment: I noticed your example `final.list` does not have each line ending with `<TAB>+` Typo?

Comment: Hi! Yes it is a typo.

I changed `cat` to `echo >` and it is giving me an output now! Thank you very much!

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> final.list

while IFS= read -r name; do
    new_name=new_${name}.fa

    cmd input-file "$name" > "$new_name"
    printf '%s\t\n' "$new_name" >> final.list
done < list_of_text.txt
```

- `> final.list` truncates (empties) the file before it gets appended.
- `while IFS= read -r line; ...` loop is the canonical method of processing one line of an input stream at a time. It is also far more robust compared to looping over an unquoted command substitution.
- `< list_of_text.txt` redirects the list as input for the while read loop.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `cat` out of the loop and replacing with `echo`, I believe you want:

```
echo > final.list
for i in $(cat list_of_text.txt)
do
    commandtool some_input_file $i > new_"$i".fa
    echo -e "new_${i}.fa\t+" >> final.list
done
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the empty line at the beginning of `final.list` which `echo > final.list` produces, you can use a command which does not produce output, such as `true > final.list` or `: > final.list`.

Comment: Or `echo -n > final.list`. :)

Comment: `echo -n` is not as widely available as `true` and `:` are.

Comment: Also, putting the whole file `list_of_text.txt` onto the command line also might run into command line length limitations. Those are far beyond the single digit kilobytes from 20 years ago, but probably still below the maximum file size of my filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this to calculate the output filename only once and to use `printf` instead of `echo -e` for portability

```
#!/bin/bash
true > final.list
for i in $(< list_of_text.txt)
do
    out="new_${i}.fa"
    commandtool some_input_file "$i" > "$out"
    printf '%s\t+\n' "$out" >> final.list
done
```